# Write function that takes list object and cut off value that returns numbers bigger

Tags: python

Write a function count() that:

(1) takes a list object and a cut-off value as two inputs
(2) returns a number of items in the list, which is bigger than the cut-off value. I am trying to use an accumulator loop pattern to do so but am struggling.

> > > count([3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 9], 5)

2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def count(l, cutoff):
    return len([e for e in l if e > cutoff])
```